# Tor Browser issue: Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available

Tags: html, youtube, tor

I have an issue on my Tor Browser currently, can't play my purchased videos and I get this message instead

"Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available"

and links me to the HTML5 support page. Am on the latest Tor browser 68.4.1esr. All other videos work fine and it's only the purchased one. I've also got all my Extensions removed still not working. So not sure what to do?

Comment: DRM protected video?